# How to display text from a textfile in html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use a text file as source for the text on my website. I just can't display it where I want it to be

I have already managed to read the text from the file, but now I'm stuck.

This is my readFile function:

```html
<script>
  function readFile(input){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var textFileText = searchFile(this.responseText, input);
        document.getElementById(input).innerHTML = this.textFileText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", textFile, true);
    xhttp.send();
  }
</script>
```

I've tried it out and it works.

This is the searchFile function:

```html
<script>
  function searchFile(text, searched){
    var output;
    var n = text.search(searched);
    output = text.substr((n+str.length+2), text.indexOf('\n'));
    return output;
  }
</script>
```

It's supposed to filter the text in the file for a specific word.

The text file looks like this:

```
[header]=text
[thing1]=more text
```

My idea is that if I call the function like this:

```
readFile("thing1");
```

The output should be "more text"

Here I call the function to display the header Text:

```html
<h2 onload = "readFile(this.id)" id = "header"></h2>
```

But then nothing gets displayed.

I've also tried this:

```html
<h2 onload = "readFile('header')" id = "header"></h2>
```

But again nothing is displayed.

Am I missing something or did I do something wrong?

Comment: append a `<p>` tag as a child of the `header` element with the text you want inside of the `<p>` tag.

Comment: Why not use a json file, read it and parse the data to a JS object? Much simpler and elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `onload` for `h2` or most tags for that matter. So instead of calling the function from the `onload`, I would simply call the function from within script tags on the page.

```
<script>readFile('header');</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only error I detected in your code is the misuse of variable =>

```
<script>
  function searchFile(text, searched){
    var output;
    var n = text.search(searched);
    //output = text.substr((n+str.length+2), text.indexOf('\n'));
    output =  text.substr((n+searched.length+2), text.indexOf('\n'));
    return output;
  }
</script>
```